# java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

Tags: weblogic

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1373)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:95)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

i have two xmls dependencies in my pom which are required at compile time in my application.
<dependency>
            <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>                    
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>b8</version>           
        </dependency>
```

I am not getting how weblogic is conflicting with these jars. Please can any one help?
If I remove these dependencies from pom, the application won't compile.

Comment: your problem aren't the dependencies.  it seems that weblogic overrides the default documentbuilderfactory. inspect the System.properties(). I guess the property 'javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory' has the value 'weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory'. @see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/DefaultDocumentLoader.html.